# How to make a periodic task in tasks.py using django and celery

Tags: python, django

I have a file tasks.py for sending email :

```py
def send_email():
    top_article = Article.objects.all()[0]

    article1 = Article.objects.all()[1:3]
    article2 = Article.objects.all()[3:5]
    last_article = Article.objects.all()[5:8]
    context = {
        'top_article': top_article,
        'article1': article1,
        'article2': article2,
        'last_article': last_article,
    }

    users_mail = UserMail.objects.all()
    for each_user in users_mail:
        if each_user.auto_send_mail == True:
            msg_plain = render_to_string('timeset/email_templates.txt')
            msg_html = render_to_string('timeset/index3.html', context)
            subject = "NEWS"
            recepient = each_user.user_mail
            send_mail(subject, msg_plain, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recepient],
                      html_message=msg_html, fail_silently=False)
        else:
            print("Not Sending")
```

and in the settings.py in django I setup a schedule :

```py
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_email_to_user': {
        'task': 'crawldata.tasks.send_email',
        'schedule': 10.0,
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a schedule for sending email into tasks.py not in settings.py anymore, how can I do that ??? I'm using celery in django.

Comment: It is recommended to use something like celeryconfig.py which has the schedule configs and then you can load that config into the Celery app.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way in your tasks.py file

```
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab


@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute=0, hour="*/12")),
    name='send_email_to_users',
    ignore_result=True
)
def send_email():
    article = Article.objects.all()
    top_article = article[0]
    article1 = article[1:3]
    article2 = article[3:5]
    last_article = article[5:8]
    context = {
        'top_article': top_article,
        'article1': article1,
        'article2': article2,
        'last_article': last_article,
        }

    users_mail = UserMail.objects.all()
    msg_plain = render_to_string('timeset/email_templates.txt')
    msg_html = render_to_string('timeset/index3.html', context)
    subject = "NEWS"
    for each_user in users_mail:
        if each_user.auto_send_mail:
            recepient = each_user.user_mail
            send_mail(subject, msg_plain, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recepient], html_message=msg_html, fail_silently=False)
        else:
            print("Not Sending")
```